# Avoiding .call() and .apply() using .bind()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-5

I'm looking for a way to accomplish a certain task and that is, going from

```
jQuery.when.apply( null, promiseArray ).done(...)
```

to

```
when( promiseArray ).done(...)
```

As you might know, `.bind()` can get used to create something like default arguments and also doing some quite nifty stuff. For instance, instead of always calling

```
var toStr = Object.prototype.toString;
// ...
toStr.call([]) // [object Array]
```

we can do it like

```
var toStr = Function.prototype.call.bind( Object.prototype.toString );
toStr([]) // [object Array]
```

This is fairly cool (even if there is a performance penality invoking `.bind()` like this, I know it and I'm aware of it), but I can't really accomplish it for jQuerys `.when` call. If you got an unknown amount of promise objects, you usually push those into an array, to then be able to pass those into `.when` like in my first code snippet above.

I'm doing this so far:

```
var when = Function.prototype.apply.bind( $.when );
```

Now we can go like

```
when( null, promiseArray ).done(...)
```

This works, but I also want to get rid of the need to pass in `null` explicitly every time. So I tried

```
var when = Function.prototype.apply.bind( $.when.call.bind( null ) );
```

but that throws at me:

```
"TypeError: Function.prototype.apply called on incompatible null"
```

I guess I'm sitting over this for too long now and can't think straight anymore. It feels like there is an easy solution. **I don't want to use any additional function** to solve this issue, I'd absolutely prefere a solution using `.bind()`.

See a complete example here: http://jsfiddle.net/pp26L/

Comment: @Raynos: yay, rub the salt into my wounded ego.. :p

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should work:

```
when = Function.prototype.apply.bind( $.when, null);
```

You just bind (or curry, if you prefer) the first argument of `.bind` and fix it to `null`.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pp26L/3/)**.

Comment: omg, I'm so sure I did that at some point. How could I miss it? At least I knew it was a fairly easy solution for a big question. Thanks @Jon!

Comment: @jAndy: Considering that your JS chops are much better than mine, it's obvious that you missed it due to fatigue. Cheers.

Answer (score 7):

[`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) accepts a variable number of arguments, so you can partially apply a method. So, instead of:

```
var when = Function.prototype.apply.bind( $.when );
```

Do this:

```
var when = Function.prototype.apply.bind( $.when , null );
```

And updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pp26L/2/