# Function.prototype.apply.bind usages?

Tags: javascript

I perfectly know the [usages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8843181/859154) for  :

`Function.prototype.bind.apply(f,arguments)`

> > Explanation - Use the original (if exists) `bind` method over `f`  with `arguments` (which its first item will be used as context to `this`)

*This code can be used ( for example) for creating new functions via constructor function with arguments*

Example :

```
function newCall(Cls) {
    return new (Function.prototype.bind.apply(Cls, arguments));
 }
```

Execution:

```
var s = newCall(Something, a, b, c);
```

**But** I came across this one : `Function.prototype.apply.bind(f,arguments)` //word swap

**Question :**

*As it is hard to understand its meaning* - in what usages/scenario would I use this code ?

Comment: You can use `apply` if you don't care about `this` and do not want to create an anonymous function (with `bind`).

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247807/avoiding-call-and-apply-using-bind

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is used to fix the first parameter of `.apply`.

For example, when you get the max value from an array, you do:

```
var max_value = Math.max.apply(null, [1,2,3]);
```

But you want to get the first parameter fixed to `null`, so you could create an new function by:

```
var max = Function.prototype.apply.bind(Math.max, null);
```

then you could just do:

```
var max_value = max([1,2,3]);
```

Comment: **very** nice example

Comment: Why it's important to pass null for bind as argument?

Comment: @sAs59 It's to give permanent null parameter on first parameter of `generated Math.max.apply` for `max` variable. When following gets called for example: `max([1,2,3])`. That calls `Math.max.apply(null, [1,2,3])`. Whereas with `Function.prototype.apply.bind(Math.max)`, The generated code for `max([1,2,3])` is just simply `Math.max.apply([1,2,3])`, which would give incorrect result.

The first parameter of Math.max.apply will be assigned to `this` reference, the second parameter (an array) would get passed to the actual parameters of the function. Without null, the `[1,2,3]` goes to `this`.

Comment: @sAs59 Then the actual parameters for Math.max would receive nothing.